# Save NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, encoder, decoder

I'm trying to save an array to `NSUserDefaults`.
I read that i have to use a encoder and decoder, but i still get the same error

```
*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<Item: 0x1e86e380>",
    "<Item: 0x1e86fd60>",
    "<Item: 0x1e86fda0>",
    "<Item: 0x1e86fde0>",
    "<Item: 0x1e86fe10>"
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
[unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown][unknown](gdb)
```

Why??

Here's my code:

This is my Model. It has `NSStrings`, `NSNumbers` and `NSMutableArrays`:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject: self.title forKey:@"title"];
    [encoder encodeObject: self.desc forKey:@"desc"];
    [encoder encodeObject: (NSNumber*) self.day forKey:@"day"];
    [encoder encodeObject: self.images forKey:@"images"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self != nil )
    {
        self.title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"title"];
        self.desc = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"desc"];
        self.day = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"day"];
        self.images = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"images"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

This is in AppDelegate's `DidFinishLaunching` method:

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedData"] == nil)
{
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"items" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [jsonParser objectWithString: contents];
    jsonParser = nil;
    items = json[@"item"];

    for(NSDictionary *itemDict in items)
    {

        Item *item = [[Item alloc] init];

        item.title = [itemDict valueForKey:@"title"];
        item.desc = [itemDict valueForKey:@"description"];
        item.day = [itemDict valueForKey:@"day"];
        item.images = [itemDict valueForKey: @"images"];

        [items addObject: item];

    }    
}
else
{

    NSData *decodedObject = [userDefault objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedData"]];
    NSArray *decodedArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: decodedObject];


    items = [decodedArray mutableCopy];

}
```

And this i have in `AppWillTerminate`:

```
   userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: items];
   [userDefault setObject: encodedObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedData"]];
```

Comment: I don't think this exception comes from the code you've shown. Add an exception breakpoint in Xcode. I suspect you're using `setObject:forKey:` with an array of `Item`s (non-property-list objects) elsewhere in your project.

Comment: yes it does. when i remove that code the error disappears..

Comment: you can only store built in Object type values in NSUserDefault, if you try to store Custom(User Defined Object) it will generate the error, so please store Built In Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreword: Understand that user defaults are not a general-purpose database. Unless the data you propose to store there is quite small, I strongly discourage you from doing this. An alternative is to store the data in a well-defined location, such as the Application Support directory.

EDIT

In the previous paragraph, I had stated that the Application Support directory should not be used for data that will change. I cannot find anything to support this. Apple's own documentation states that it is "where your app stores any type of file that supports the app but is not required for the app to run," that user data should not be stored there, and that each app should create and maintain its own directory inside it, rather than write to its top level. Not at all certain where I picked up this bit of fiction, and am sorry for having perpetuated it.

END EDIT

That being said, when the compiler complains of "non-property value(s)," that means that you're attempting to write something that is not a `NSArray,` `NSDictionary,` `NSString,` `NSData,` `NSDate` or `NSNumber.`

You are correct that your own objects need to make use of NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver. But just because you're implementing your `NSCoding` methods in your model object doesn't change the fact that it's not a property list value.

What you need to do is to use `NSKeyedArchiver` *before* you attempt to store each of your objects. This produces an instance of `NSData` that can be stored as a property list object.

Comment: Why would you avoid the Application Support folder?